# How to include link path in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

In html, in order to make a link we show folder and its path. For example:

```html
<h2><a href="about-us.html">ABOUT COMPANY</a></h2>
```

Now, How we do this in wordpress? Say, if we have a "About us" page created and I want to redirect someone from Main Page into the About us page?

Comment: you can place the link inside a menu or create a hard coded link to that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set page id inside "get_permalink" function and call like this way,

```
<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>">ABOUT COMPANY</a></h2>
```